# Python function getBetweenHTML

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, urllib2

This is a short question:

Where does the function getBetweenHTML() come from, e.g. urllib2 or something i am not sure. 
Could anyone also give me an explanation of this function or better alternatives, thanks.

Code syntax:

```
import urllib2
url = urllib2.urlopen('http://google.com').read()
scraped = getBetweenHTML(url,'<div class="question">',"</div>)
print scraped
```

e.g. prints a question

Edit: I've found the solution, I actually made my own function, that's the reason I couldn't find it anywhere, I coded it myself in bs4, for anyone who needs it:

```
def getBetweenHTML(strSource, strStart,strEnd):
start = strSource.find(strStart) + len(strStart)
end = strSource.find(strEnd,start)
return strSource[start:end]
```

Comment: Is that your actual code? Because it appears to be missing a quote mark on the third line. This implies to me that you're transcribing the code from memory rather than copying actual working code. Are you 100% sure `getBetweenHTML` was the exact name of the function? Furthermore, when you ran this code, did you do it using a REPL or did you run it as a stand-alone script? If it's the former, the namespace may still be polluted by modules that were previously imported. What is the output when you do `print getBetweenHTML.__module__`?

Comment: No, this isn't the full code. You're right, it might be because I imported a module as x, thanks, I'll look at it and answer you in a minute.

Comment: issue has been fixed, thanks, @Kevin